# Does a probability distribution that's $\epsilon$-far from a uniform distribution need to be altered in many indices?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider probability distributions over $\left \{1,\dots,n \right \}$, and denote the uniform one by $\nu$. I am interested in analyzing distributions that are far from $\nu$ according to the [variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), meaning distributions $\mu$ for which

$$d(\mu,\nu)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \left |\mu(i)-\frac{1}{n} \right | \geq \epsilon$$
For a small $0 <\epsilon < 1$. I am trying to understand if that restricts $\mu$ in the sense that there should be a **non-negligible** amount of $\mu$ that corresponds to indices for which $\mu(i)\neq \frac{1}{n}$. This question is posed somewhat vague, as we can measure this by either the actual amount of such indices, but it is more natural to look at the total probability of selecting such indices. I am refering to the latter kind. By non-negligible, I conjecture something of the kind $\Omega(\epsilon)$ probability or any polynomial lower bound in $\epsilon$.

Note we assume a large $n$. My first idea was to look at the following probability assignment
$$\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
which seems to satisfy the conditions needed w.p $\frac{2}{n}$, but has the implicit assumption $n \leq 2/\epsilon$ which is false. This means that in a sense, the deviations we expect to alter to probabilities with to achieve the required distance are of order $\approx \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ thus should be spread across many indices. I am having a difficult time formalizing this into a coherent argument, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I now realized that the two notions for measuring these indices are congruent, the probability of choosing indices for which $\mu(i)$ changed is the same as the number of indices (divided by $n$) as all the changes cancel out. So both interpretations are fine.

Comment: Are you asking, if $d(\mu,\nu) > \epsilon$, to find an estimate for the number of $i$ such that $\mu(i)\ne 1/n$?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Yes, namely show it is $\Omega(\epsilon n$), which implies the probability selecting those under $\mu$ is $\Omega(\epsilon)$ (again, if true, and I strongly think so)

Comment: @AlexOrtiz $n$ being a natural number is not bounded by a number smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$, it can be as large as we desire, and in fact since I mostly care about asymptotics you can assume it's larger than some constant $N$. The reason for this assumption is the probabilities must be positive.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz First of all sorry as I was mistaken since the assumption is $n \leq \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. This is not feasible because the probability $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is negative. So this examples holds for certain cases but not for large $n$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I see now. Point being $\epsilon$ is fixed, so once $n$ is large enough, we won't be able to subtract $\epsilon$ from $1/n$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. This problem comes from the world of property testing where we assume a large input, and the cases where $n =\text{poly}(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ are not interesting.